# Pretty-print a Pandas DataFrame groupby

Tags: pandas

Is there and easy way to pretty-print a pandas.DataFrame.groupby.count() result?

My code is:

```
print out_df.groupby(['Symbol','Account'])['OrderID'].count()
```

My output is:

```
Symbol  Account 
XXXXX   123    34
        124    32
YYYYY   123    22
        124    24
dtype: int64
```

I would like to have:

```
Symbol  Account Count
XXXXX   123     34
        124     32
YYYYY   123     22
        124     24
```

With the column header `Count` and without the `dtype`.

I guess I could use:

```
print orders_str[:orders_str.rfind('\n')]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can call `.agg(["count"])`:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
s = ["xxx", "yyy", "zzz"]
symbols = [random.choice(s) for i in range(100)]
s = [10, 20, 30]
account = [random.choice(s) for i in range(100)]
s = [11, 22, 33]
ids = [random.choice(s) for i in range(100)]
print df.groupby(["Account", "Symbols"])['OrderID'].agg(["count"])
```

output:

```
                 count
Account Symbols       
10      xxx         11
        yyy         13
        zzz          9
20      xxx          6
        yyy         11
        zzz         14
30      xxx          6
        yyy         16
        zzz         14
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print pd.DataFrame({'Count': out_df.groupby(['Symbol', 'Account']).size()})
```

Output:

```
                Count
Symbol  Account 
XXXXX   123     34
        124     32
YYYYY   123     22
        124     24
```